# add incremental date in first column of the file using awk or sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I want to add date in the first column of the file which starts from "1950/01/01" (format : %m/%d/%Y) and date should increment with each row using awk or sed. ***When adding date, leap year also needs to be considered***..

File contents are:

```
1,2,3,4
3,4,5,6
4,7,8,9
```

Expected output:

```
1950/01/01,1,2,3,4
1950/02/01,3,4,5,6
1950/03/01,4,7,8,9
```

So far I have manage to add formatted date in the first column but not able to increment it with every row.

```
awk -v date="$(date -d '1950/01/01' '+%m/%d/%Y')" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }  ; {print date, $0}' inout.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Gawk`

**Input**

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4
3,4,5,6
4,7,8,9
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -v date="$( date -d '1950/01/01' '+%s' )" '{print strftime("%Y/%d/%m",date)","$0; date+=86400}' file
1950/01/01,1,2,3,4
1950/02/01,3,4,5,6
1950/03/01,4,7,8,9
```

**Explanation**

```
 awk -v date="$( date -d '1950/01/01' '+%s' )" '{ # call awk set var date with timestamp

        print strftime("%Y/%d/%m",date) "," $0;   # print date, sep comma and current line 
        date+=86400                               # one day = 86400 seconds, just increment
 }
 ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with bash and GNU date:

```
a=1950/01/01
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$a,$line"; a=$(date +%Y/%m/%d -d "$a 1 day"); done < file
```

Output:

```
1950/01/01,1,2,3,4
1950/01/02,3,4,5,6
1950/01/03,4,7,8,9
```